# Apache2 doesnt redirect non-www to www

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I have a apache2 serving an application which works fine on [www.domain.co.uk](http://www.domain.co.uk) but when going to domain.co.uk (non www) it doesn't redirect the traffic. I added a redirect to my .conf file and it still doesn't work. See below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.co.uk
    Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias domain.co.uk
    # Actual server configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know how to redirect the non-www traffic to www (or fix my configuration!)?

Comment: I can't test it myself (so won't add as an answer), but is ServerAlias needed?

Comment: Why do both virtual hosts listen for the non-www domain?

Comment: @AdrianWragg after I removed all of the ServerAlias configurations the redirection worked. Thank you. If you add the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Saif Done. Also, just a hopefully helpful note for the future - if you're going to use example domains, the IANA have reserved "example.com" (and a few others) for this purpose. This prevents linking to unrelated sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate areas of the configuration capturing `domain.co.uk` - one is in the redirection, the other (through your use of `ServerAlias`) in the configuration that serves the content. The second capture is overriding the first.

To resolve the issue, simply remove the line:

```
ServerAlias domain.co.uk
```

and restart Apache.